# A semicolon is being added when using the ion-grid element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm building a simple app in angular with the latest ionic-framework. I want to use the  elements which is working fine. The problem that I have is that for some reason the semicolon (;) is being added right after the grid when I open de app. I added a image of what it looks like.

[Screenshot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEoTV.png)

I created a new app with tabs. This is my code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Tab Two
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
      ion-col
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
      ion-col
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
      ion-col
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
      ion-col
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

I appreciate your help on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is fixed in 4.7.4, see https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases/tag/v4.7.4